# React Router defining my own Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

So the implementation of the `<Link />` onClick which handles the router navigation is simple:

```
const { history } = this.context.router;

history.push(to);
```

That is pulled from the [github repo](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L47)

So in my [application](http://jsbin.com/yogakudodu/edit?html,js,output) it should work, because the context gets passed down from the `<Router>` component right?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  render() {
    const home = () => (<div>Home</div>);
    const about = () => (<div>About</div>);
    const { history } = this.context.router;

    console.log("History", history);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={about} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

But as you can see in the console output, the history object is undefined....

Comment: with `withRouter`

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify Azium comment:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
  }

  render() {
    const home = () => (<div>Home</div>);
    const about = () => (<div>About</div>);
    const { history } = this.props;

    console.log("History", history);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={about} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const AppWithRouter = withRouter(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <AppWithRouter />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

`withRouter` gives you match, location, history on the props.

Comment: Yeah, works fine. What are you trying it on? the jsbin?

Comment: jsbin has lots of warnings and errors related to library imports

Comment: Yeah you can ignore all of them! Plus you'll need to do `ReactRouterDOM.withRouter` instead....